# Low f/stop = fast lens?

Tags: f-stop

I have heard of lenses being described as fast that have f/stop values of f1.2 and f/2.8.

My question is why are such low f/stop lenses called fast?

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. The focus here is on the "why."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the wikipedia, I couldn't have said it better myself.

> A lens with a larger maximum aperture (that is, a smaller minimum f-number) is called a "fast lens" because it delivers more light intensity (illuminance) to the focal plane, achieving the same exposure with a faster shutter speed.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the why "**low** f/stop" part: this is a ratio. Hence the smaller the number, the bigger the amount of light.